# MongoDb Aggregation - sliding window averages?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use the mongodb aggregation framework to average the last hour of "scores" per term, every minute.  I've no issues grouping by minute of course.. just am not clear on the best way to group by minute but *then* have mongo go back an hour per minute to calculate the average score.  After searching here and finding some options, I get the sense that $bucket is not the best approach due to performance reasons, same for map/reduce.. so just looking for opinions.  I won't need to run this query often as I'll typically be doing this running calculation in my application every minute.. but need to first "seed" the data  based off the raw data I've collected, and then would also like to have this query available to run in the case of a service outage and my running calculation stops..

sample raw documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603e472aba52820ab3e139ae"),
    "term" : "sports",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-03-02T14:09:46.701Z"),
    "score" : -0.331166666666667,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6031272aba52820ab3e139ef"),
    "term" : "sports",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-03-02T14:09:55.000Z"),
    "score" : 1.05
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("io12iopeipweipqeqweqwewq"),
    "term" : "food",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-03-10T16:02:12.091Z"),
    "score" : 0.25,
}
```

I'd like a result set similar to

```
term   | for minute "x"      | average of scores from (x - 1 hour) to x
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sports | 03/31/2021 14:10:00 | (average of all "sports" scores from 3/31/2021 13:10:00 to 3/31/2021 14:10:00)
food   | 03/31/2021 14:10:00 | (average of all "food" scores from 3/31/2021 13:10:00 to 3/31/2021 14:10:00)
sports | 03/31/2021 14:11:00 | (average of all "sports" scores from 3/31/2021 13:11:00 to 3/31/2021 14:11:00)
```

Thank you in advance for any advice someone might be willing to offer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$term",
         min_created: { $min: "$created_at" },
         data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         score: {
            $map: {
               input: { // generate sequence of 60 Minutes
                  $map: {
                     input: { $range: [0, 60] },
                     in: { $add: ["$min_created", { $multiply: ["$$this", 60, 1000] }] }
                  }
               },
               as: "ts",
               in: {
                  range_start: "$$ts",
                  range_end: { $add: ["$$ts", 1000 * 60 * 60] },
                  scores: {
                     $filter: { // select data fitting in range
                        input: "$data",
                        cond: {
                           $and: [
                              { $gte: ["$$this.created_at", "$$ts"] },
                              { $lt: ["$$this.created_at", { $add: ["$$ts", 1000 * 60 * 60] }] }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { // make average score
      $set: {
         score: {
            $map: {
               input: "$score",
               as: "score",
               in: {
                  range_start: "$$score.range_start",
                  range_end: "$$score.range_end",
                  score: { $avg: "$$score.scores.score" }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { // suppress empty ranges
      $set: {
         score: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$score",
               cond: { $ne: ["$$this.score", null] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

You did not provide the desired output (as JSON) so I can just guess. You may need to do some cosmetic changes. I hope the principle should be clear.

Some stages you can combine into one stage. However, I separated them for better visibility.

`$map` should work much better than `$reduce`, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53503

Comment: I think this is on the right track; but it only gives me the scores from min_created til 60 minutes after min_created, and I'd like it to be from min_created til "now".   So basically, for every minute from min_created until now, I want the average score for the past hour. I'll work on modifying this query to do that.  I also had a typo on the "minute" field in my example above so I've fixed it.